# Producing xml-signature with windows line-break running in LINUX

Tags: java, xml, linux, xml-signature

First of all, sorry for my poor English!!

I have to digitally sign some XML documents to send to Chilean SII, including in them the Digital Signature. When I'm developing under **JAVA** in **Windows**, I can send documents and get an OK as response. Documents as sent as POST, including some headers before XML Message. If I use **\r\n** as line-break, the response is OK, if I use only **\n**, I get a HTTP 500 response. So I decide to use **\r\n**

Next step is to compile and package my program in a jar and place it in a **Linux Server**.
When I execute the program and send a document, if I use the **\n** line-break I get a HTTP 500 response, the same that I received in Windows. If I use **\r\n**, I can send the xml but I receive an error message from server: **"XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."**
The unique difference I can see between the signed XML in Windows and a signed one in Linux is the **line-break character**. It's like the server is expecting **\r\n**, that is used in windows, but when I execute it in Linux it is used **\n** as line-break .

Is there some magical sentence I can add in my java code to force the use of \r\n as line-break, even when I execute it under Linux??

Note: I'm using java7 and crypto libraries form the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PrintWriter to generate the post request - in particular its `println()` calls - you can override PrintWriter to make it use the line break separator that you wish as follows:

```
static PrintWriter newPrintWriter(Writer out, String lineSep)
{
    return new PrintWriter(out) {
        public void println() {
            print(lineSep);
        }
    };
}
```

Then you could wrap your output stream for the post code with something like this for Unix/Linux line separator:

```
try(PrintWriter out = newPrintWriter(yourOutputStream, "\n")) {
   out.println("whatever");
}
```

or for Windows style line separator:

```
try(PrintWriter out = newPrintWriter(yourOutputStream, "\r\n")) {
   out.println("whatever");
}
```